# Ошибка 404 при переходе по ссылке вглубь сайта

Tags: yii, apache, nginx

Установил на VPS сервер *apache* и *nginx*, настроил на использование *yii* сам *nginx* с такой конфигурацией:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name site.com.ua www.site.com.ua;
root /var/www/ua;
index index.html index.php;
set $yii_bootstrap "index.php";
charset utf-8;

location / {
        index  index.html $yii_bootstrap;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$yii_bootstrap?$args;
    }

location ~ ^/(protected|framework|themes/\w+/views) {
        deny  all;
    }

location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://[::1]:8081/$request_uri;
}
location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
            access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
```

}

Вот конфигурация *apache*:

```
<Directory /var/www/ua>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        DirectoryIndex index.php

        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            <IfModule mod_mime.c>
                    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
            </IfModule>
            <FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
                    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
            </FilesMatch>

            php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
            php_flag track_vars On
            php_flag register_globals Off
            php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen Off

            #php_value include_path .
            #php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
            #php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/:/usr/share/php/tcpdf/
        </IfModule>

</Directory>
```

Когда захожу на главную страницу сайта, то нормально работает, а если пробую по ссылке перейти (например, `www.site.com/order/index`),  то получаю ошибку `Apache 404 Not Found`.

Как мне правильно сконфигурировать сервер?

Comment: смотрите в логе `apache`, что именно он пытался найти и не смог.

Comment: Зачем вам два веб-сервера?

Comment: Использую в связке с nginx для ускорения работы сервера

Comment: @Etki, некоторые довольно распространённые фреймворки буквально напичканы развесистыми `.htaccess`-ами, без которых «просто не работает». у новичка обязательно возникнут трудности при «переводе» заложенной логики в формат директив `nginx`-а.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin в yii этого нет

Comment: @Etki, возможно. хотя автор вопроса, вроде бы, нашёл у себя .htaccess.

Comment: Потому что он использует два веб-сервера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена! Оказывается была отключена директива AllowOverride None. Я поставил ее в значение All. Эта директива включает поддержку apache2 файлов .htacccess который у меня отвечал за адресацию внутренних страниц. VPS установлен на UNIX системе в файле /etc/apache2/apache2.conf  добавил вот такие строчки

```
<Directory /var/www/ua>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

затем выполнил команду `a2enmod rewrite` и все заработало!

Comment: Большое спасибо. Помогло

Answer (score 0):

вижу как минимум одну (предположительно) ошибку:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
```

а должно быть, насколько я понимаю, без привязки к концу строки:

```
location ~ \.php {
```

Comment: Спасибо, но это не помогло (

Comment: повторяю: смотрите `error.log` сервера `apache`

Comment: я нашел этот error но как мне его скопировать сюда? сижу через терминал в ubuntu

Comment: скопируйте строки, появившиеся в момент выдачи ошибки, и добавьте их в вопрос, нажав кнопку «править».

Comment: Кажется я разобрался надо добавить директиву AllowOverride , он просто не видит файл .htaccess. Только не знаю куда его вставить в конфигурации сервера

Comment: у вас есть эта директива.

Comment: нет ее там вобще

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25186/discussion-between-modelfak-and-alexander-barakin).

Comment: нет, все правильно, `my-exploitable-image.php.png` обрабатываться не должен.

Answer (score 0):

`proxy_pass http://[::1]:8081/$request_uri;`

правильнее будет так:

`proxy_pass http://[::1]:8081$request_uri;`